# Many to many relationship, select rows based on values in list

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many

I want to select `group_runs` based on a list of `group_runners.player` and I'm having issue getting rid of results that don't have all the values on that list. In this case `group_runs` with `id = 2` shouldn't be returned because it contains only `1,3`.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group_runs`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dungeon_id` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `difficulty` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `time` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group_runners`
(
    `run_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `player` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`run_id`) REFERENCES `group_runs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO `group_runs` VALUES (NULL, 1, 1, 160); #run 1
INSERT INTO `group_runs` VALUES (NULL, 1, 1, 150); #run 2

#Add to run 1 player (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO `group_runners` VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `group_runners` VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `group_runners` VALUES (1, 3);

#Add to run 2 player (1, 3)
INSERT INTO `group_runners` VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO `group_runners` VALUES (2, 3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT runs.id, runs.time, GROUP_CONCAT(runners.player) players
FROM group_runs runs
JOIN group_runners runners
ON runs.id = runners.run_id
WHERE
    runs.dungeon_id = 1 AND
    runs.difficulty = 1 AND
    runners.player IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY runs.id;
```

| id | time | players |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 160 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 150 | 1,3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hh77esM4tAkUtTHt8Pa4uk/4)

Comment: `HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT runners.player ORDER BY runners.player) = '1,2,3'`

Comment: @Akina That is something... How about performance with this one? I feel like it's still selecting all these rows but returning only the one that matches `HAVING`. Is that true?

Comment: *How about performance with this one?* Test.. *Is that true?* Server is the only who desides how to process the query. We can suppose only..